# override what objects.all() returns when using PassThroughManager in django-model-utils?

Tags: django, model

I'd like to use
[PassThroughManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager).

Example covers how to define custom manager methods, but can't find info on how to change the *default* queryset, ie. objects.all().

How can I specify what my objects.all() will return when using PassThroughManager?

--- edit --

For future readers, 
django 1.7 seems to have PassThroughManager built-in

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just override the `all()` method on your custom `QuerySet`?

```
class PostQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def all(self):
        ...
```

Comment: yeah, thought about it, but then haven't seen an example doing it so was afraid of it. (most examples on the net override manager's get_queryset method). and _clone() stuff worries me.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all

Comment: I would personally not override either `get_queryset` or `all` since those are used in other places of django. Its always risky to override the default behavior. Now your admin will not show everything.

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 3.0+, you can no longer override the `all` function in QuerySet. The latest solution for this without having to use any third party is:

```
from django.db import models

class CustomQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    pass

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = CustomQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
        return qs.filter(...)    # your custom logic here

class CustomModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

[Django 3.1 Documentation on custom manager & queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager)

Answer (score 0):

See the @jproffitt answer, but if you really need to define that method in manager

I guess you can do:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from model_utils import managers


class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        # ... Your custom method

class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    pass

MyThThroughManager = managers.create_pass_through_manager_for_queryset_class(MyManager, MyQuerySet)
```

I saw the [model utils docs](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager) and [its code](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/master/model_utils/managers.py#L248)